# how can i test sharepoint custom web service

Tags: web-services, sharepoint

hi all
i coded a custom web service for sharepoint in a remote machine and will deploy it later to the host machine
but how programs do i need to install to my computer to test that web service

Comment: dont i need to deploy it to the host to understand if it really works?

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool such as

- [Storm](http://storm.codeplex.com/)
- [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/what-is-soapui.html)
- [Web Service Studio](http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/)

(All open source)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a test application to sit on the same system as the web service.

It will locally fire the webservice and some of the test fixtures will only monitor what it returns.

The rest of the fixtures should examine what the webservice actually interacts with on the server side.

ie: If you have a webservice that accepts a command then starts a Workflow, you would:

a) Ensure that the correct response is given by the webservice when invalid input is given
b) Ensure on the server side that the correct workflow is instigated and started with the correct initialisation data.

You would probably need many, many test cases depending on what your webservice actually does.